# What is the best way to implement the functionalities of BitmapImage without inheriting?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

this.container.addElement(myCustomImageInstance as GraphicElement) must display the test image.

```
package com.www
{
    import spark.primitives.BitmapImage;
    import spark.primitives.supportClasses.GraphicElement;

    public class BaseTest extends GraphicElement
    {       
        public function BaseTest()
        {
            super();
        }

        /* stuff */
    }

    public class MyCustomImage extends BaseTest
    {
        private var _img:BitmapImage = null;

        public function MyCustomImage()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function get img():BitmapImage {
            if (!_img) {
                _img = new BitmapImage();
                _img.source = /* BitmapData of a test image */;
            }
            return _img;
        }

        /* It obviously does not work, any ideas?
        override public function createDisplayObject():DisplayObject {
            return img.displayObject;
        }

        override public function get displayObject():DisplayObject {
            return img.displayObject;
        }
        */

    }

}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Your question isn't very clear — please be a bit more specific vis. what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I really want to add (addElement) any instances of MyCustomImage to a DisplayObjectContainer. Rendering is the BitmapImage displayobject.

Comment: To answer my own question. BaseTest must extend Group for example and add the element BitmapImage.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `mx:Image`, the spark `BitmapImage` class does not include member functions for loading bitmap data.  Hence the `source` property you are trying to push your URL into is only intended to take actual bitmap data (something either returned from an SWFLoader or Loader, or an embedded image file).  Please see the AS3 Documentation: [s:BitmapImage#source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/BitmapImage.html#source)

Although you can technically place a URL in the embed directive (eg. `@Embed("http://...image.jpg")`), I assume since you are using ActionScript instead of MXML, you intend to dynamically load your images.

In that case, you'll either need to use [mx.controls.Image](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html), or use a separate [mx.controls.SWFLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) or [flash.display.Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) to load the image that you need.  You should note that the loading process is asynchronous.

You might find something like the following tutorial helpful, which shows how to use `flash.display.Loader`, together with `s:BitmapImage`, to function like mx:Image:
http://polygeek.com/2452_flex_extending-spark-bitmapimage

Comment: Thank you for notifying the problem but it's actually not my problem. I edit my message.